# Fetch row ID from a mysql table's specific column with exact string

Tags: php, mysql

Ok, first of all, I am new to PHP and MySQL. And what I am trying to achieve here is a bit complicated so please bear with me. I will try to explain my problem as simply as possible:

I have a MySQL table named "tblstaff" in my database. In that table, I have a column named "BranchName". I need to fetch the ID of that particular row that matches my string "Washington" from the column "BranchName".

For Example if the Row with the string "Washington" in the "BranchName" column has the ID 4, I want 4 to be fetched.

So far this is how I am trying to achieve this:

```
$cmssid = "SELECT * FROM tblstaff WHERE BranchName = 'Washington'";
```

I know there's plenty I am missing and/or doing wrong here as I am a total novice in coding.

Here's a snapshot of the table:

[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What you posted should work, given you're using the right function to fetch and check if there is such a record. The api used to connect/query with, is unknown though.

Comment: However, and in addition to my above comment is that you'd need to add to the `WHERE` clause with the `AND` logical operator. Yet, if there is only 1 record for it, no need to use an additional clause. So, what isn't working the way you'd like it to? You never said.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner No it wouldn't work, using `select *` will return the entire rows that match Washington under `BranchName`. What he needs is to replace `*` with `id`. He wants to see only the row id that matches `BranchName = Washington` - not everything else in the row.

Comment: @t1f Why wouldn't selecting all not work?

Comment: Because he stated he doesn't want to see everything in the row - just the row ID number. Read his question again. Indeed I didn't mean it wouldn't work per se, just not how he expects it, per his requirement.

Comment: whatever.................. I'm out of this one. You deal with him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing: `"SELECT * FROM tblstaff WHERE BranchName = 'Washington'";`

..which returns the entire rows information that has `Washington` under `BranchName`.

What you want to do is replace `*` with the **name** of the **id column**, in this case, **id** - so you can see just the actual **id number** for the rows that match `Washington` under `BranchName`

Like this:

```
SELECT id FROM tblstaff WHERE BranchName = 'Washington'
```

It will return **all** row id numbers that contain `Washington` under the column `BranchName`.

> doing `select *` returns everything contained in the rows that matches
>   the `where clause`
>
> doing `select <specific column name>` returns only that specific
>   column value, that you mentioned, in the rows that matched your `where clause`